# What features do I need to consider when picking an installer for an application?

Tags: windows, installation

We distribute an application that runs only on Window's machines (XP and up).  I have been distributing by building an exe with WINRAR that has generally worked well but I have run into a problem as we move to support Vista and Win7 in that the application path is going to be dependent on the OS.  So I either have to build an OS dependent WINRAR exe or join the modern age and use an installer.

I have scanned the websites of a couple of the installers for sale and the open source ones but since I have limited programming knowledge I am a bit overwhelmed by the choices.

It could be that the correct answer is that because we are not making any registry changes any of the installers will do.

Comment: I feel your pain selecting an installer.  On the few occasions I have had to deal with this, I found the available choices lacking in key features and/or poorly documented.  Wish I had useful advice on the subject, but it is a good question.

Comment: PyNEwbit - Could you detail your requirements a bit more?  Are you just installing files into a single directory?  Or do any of the following apply: Fonts?  Registry keys?  COM registrations?  Multiple directories? Installing dependent packages such as Visual C++ runtime or .net framework?  Separate 32-bit and 64-bit builds? Do you support upgrading from one version to the next?  What's the disk footprint of your install?  Knowing all of this would likely generate better answers.

Comment: @PyNEwbie What is the problem with WinRAR self-extracting installer on Vista/7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, the install process of your application is simple: just copy the files. In this case, any install tool would do its job. You can try the following:

- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)
- [WiX Toolset](http://wix.codeplex.com/)

The first two are easier to learn. WiX creates Windows Installer packages and has a steep learning curve; although in your case you could merely follow the [WiX Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/) to build your setup package.

---

If your installation procedure is so simple that it does not require an install, users of your application may like if you just give them a zip package which they can extract to any directory. Of course, this depends on the target users. Anyway, it could be a good option in addition to install package.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the key distinction is whether or not you want to deliver a .msi Windows Installer package or not. Corporates prefer that because it makes large scale deployment easier for them. But .msi packages are harder to create and have a steep learning curve.